# How can I get the character ʟ̟ ?

Tags: accents, tipa

I would like to get the character 'ʟ̟' (small caps L with + diacritic).

I am using the TIPA package. When I combine the TIPA for the L with the TIPA for the diacritic, my code won't compile. I get the error `! Argument of \T3\; has an extra }.`

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}    
\usepackage{tipa}    
\begin{document}

This works: \textipa{\;L}    
And this works: \begin{IPA}\;L\end{IPA}    
And this works: \textscl

This diacritic works: \begin{IPA} \|+l \end{IPA}

%But this stops it compiling \begin{IPA} \|+\;L \end{IPA}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\begin{IPA} \|+{\;L} \end{IPA}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
\textipa{\|+{\;L}}
```

with additional braces.

The command `\|` executes `\@omniaccent` that requires two arguments, so with `\|+\;L` the second argument is `\;`, which is wrong.